# Unreachable Statement Error; No Infinite Loops or Return Statements Prior to the point of issue

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have an unreachable statement error on the following two lines of code:

```
System.out.println("We Made It!");
```

and

```
                switch (runs[i].charAt(2)) {
                    case 'A':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0xA); //0b1010);
                        continue;
                        //if hexadecimal is 11 concatenate an "a" to the string
                    case 'B':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0xB);//0b1011);
                        continue;
                        //if hexadecimal is 12 concatenate an "a" to the string
                    default:
                        continue;
```

I suspect that the issue is that code after a switch statement is unreachable. How would I get the unreachable switch statement to execute after after the first one in the else statement?

Here is the entire method:

```
public static byte[] stringToRle(String rleString) {
    //variable declarations
    String[] runs = rleString.split(":");
    ArrayList<Byte> tempData = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    //start of for loop
    //iterate through every element of the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
        //if the string in the array has a length of 2, execute the following code
        if (runs[i].length() == 2) {
        //execute the switch statement twice, once for each letter of the two letter string    
            for(int j = 0; j < runs[i].length(); j++) {
                switch (runs[i].charAt(j)) {
                    case '0':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0x0);
                        continue;
                    case '1':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0x1);
                        continue;
                    case '2':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0x2);
                        continue;
                    default:
                        continue;
                }
            }
        }
        //if the string in the array has a length of 3, execute the following code
        else if(runs[i].length() == 3) {
                //the following code executes fine
                switch (runs[i].charAt(1)) {
                    case '0':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0xA);
                        continue;
                    case '1':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0xB);
                        continue;
                    case '2':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0xC);
                        continue;
                    default:
                        continue;
                }
                //FIRST UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
                //FIRST UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
                //FIRST UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
                //FIRST UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
                //FIRST UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
                switch (runs[i].charAt(2)) {
                    case 'A':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0xA); //0b1010);
                        continue;
                        //if hexadecimal is 11 concatenate an "a" to the string
                    case 'B':
                        tempData.add((byte) 0xB);//0b1011);
                        continue;
                        //if hexadecimal is 12 concatenate an "a" to the string
                    default:
                        continue;
                }
            //SECOND UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
            //SECOND UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
            //SECOND UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
            //SECOND UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
            //SECOND UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
            System.out.println("We Made It!");
        }
    }
    byte[] array = new byte[tempData.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = tempData.get(i);
        System.out.println(" " + array[i]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`continue` for for loops. While you have used it with `switch` cases. So when you place continue in every switch case it continue the for loop. And code below to that won't get execute at all. Because every continue in switch is actually restarting the loop.

**Looks like you need to use `break` instead of `continue` in your `switch` cases to break the case.**

Comment: @ScaryWombat Continue will definitely work if it is surrounded by for. What I mean is that if we place continue in every switch condition (As done in code), it will lead to unreachable code inside the for loop after  switch statement. And that's what happening here.

Comment: Got you.  I was looking at the endless loop code.

Comment: Sorry was not me.

Comment: I see what you mean, the "continue" initiates the next iteration at the top of the loop without running the code below the "continue" statement.. Thank you!